# Laravel Route Variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel, if I've two or more routes like:

```
Route::get('/{username}', 'UsersController');
Route::get('/{album}', 'AlbumsController');
```

and a user requested a page like `www.example.com/foo`, then how will Laravel figure out if the user has opted for either for the user profile or the album's page.

Answer (score 5):

It wont - it is impossible for Laravel to know which - so you cant do that.

You need to make your routes

```
Route::get('/user/{username}', 'UsersController');
Route::get('/album/{album}', 'AlbumsController');
```

The only other way you *might* do it is if maybe there is no username matching `foo` - you could have it try for an album called `foo` - but then you run into other issues - like what if a username and album have the same name...

Comment: Okay. It means that I can have it for username only and add the album prefix to the next. Is there a solution to it in Laravel 5?

Comment: There is no 'solution' and there never will be. If you type   `yourdomain.com/foo` - then it is impossible to know what the user wanted to do - unless you had specific rules (like regex for usernames or something). Honestly - there is no reason not to just use `/user` and `/album` - they are very clean urls and look good - including for SEO

Comment: Good answer, except I prefer using plural -- `'users/{user}'` and `'albums/{album}'`

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to do what you want but it's really bad practice. It will confuse the user and yourself after you look at the code a few months later.

```
#btw, this is in laravel 5 

Route::any('foo', function($verb)
{
    switch($verb)
    {
        case 'album':
        return view('somepage');

        case 'user':
        return view('some_user');

        default:
        return view('randompage');
    }
});
```

i might of done the code wrong but did it without testing. But you get the point.

EDIT: just tested it, not possible. besides its a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just structure URLs how they’re intended to be? A resource name and identifier (i.e. `albums/{album_id}`).

What happens if a user creates an album with the same name as a user? How is your application going to differentiate between the two? What if you add other object types (like an event). It’s impossible to assume *every* object in your application is going to have a non-conflicting name.

Stop trying to go against the grain and just structure your URLs as per conventions. It’ll save you a lot of headaches in development.